# The hole in a character

Tags: single-word-requests, typography

Forgive any naivety. I have come from SO to SE to ask a question.

I am looking for a font, where the hole in a character ie O, A, P, Q. Can be used to insert an image. I do not need a recommendation for a font. But what I am asking for is the word used to explain this area. Can someone please provide me with the specific word that explains the whitespace within these particular letters.

Comment: You’re right: there is a specific word for this. I’ll have to look it up.

Comment: I'm sure I have read this on stumble upon/ a Christmas cracker/ a penguin bar. Just can't track it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In typography](http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/typeface_anatomy.pdf), anything that isn't ink is referred to as whitespace. An area of whitespace that is either partially or entirely enclosed by a letter, whether uppercase or lowercase, is typically called a **counter**. However, there is an exception to this: in the lowercase letter "e," the whitespace is also referred to as an "eye" (as per its usual shape).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the reason it’s called a counter has to do with how the original type was carved out of metal.  Somewhere around here I have Bringhurst’s revision to Warren Chappel’s *A Short History of the Printed Word*.  Also, I’m not sure that you can use the indefinite article “a” for *whitespace*: it seems like a mass noun.

Comment: @tchrist who's being schooled? Is it me? Is it true that uppercase exists because of the days of print where capital letters were kept at the top of the case. Not being facetious, genuine question.

Comment: Fair enough—I've changed "a whitespace" to "an area of whitespace"; otherwise, you are assigning a mass noun to an discretized noun, which is also awkward.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat: That should probably be asked as a separate question, but it looks like the answer may very well be "yes."

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Yes, that’s why. I believe there’s a question here on that very thing. BTW, if you’re interested in that sort of thing, the book I mention above is highly recommended. Also *The Elements of Typographic Style*.

Comment: @tchrist, according to the OED (I think I had this somewhere veeeery far in the back of my head, too), the reason it’s called a counter is because of the tool used to make them. These areas were especially tricky to cut into the steel punches, and the most common device used to cut out these areas was the _counterpunch_, so named because it was in effect a ‘reverse’ of the actual punch used to produce the glyph. Can’t seem to find an image of what exactly they look(ed) like, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yep. If you “Look Inside” at the [Amazon link to *A Brief History of the Printed Word*](http://www.amazon.com/Short-History-Printed-Word/dp/0881791547), you can search for *counterpunch*. There are illustrations. There are even *counter-counterpunches*. :)

Answer (score 1):

The enclosed or partially enclosed whitespace in a character is usually called a **[counter](http://www.proximasoftware.com/fontexpert/terms/#c)**. Examples of characters with a counter include *C*, *e*, *S* and *H*. The round or curved enclosed portion of letters like *D*, *g*, *p* and *o* can also be called a **[bowl](http://www.proximasoftware.com/fontexpert/terms/#b)**.